# How to enable HTTPS on Symfony 4 local web server

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, https, server

I'm working on Symfony 4 project locally using symfony local web server. How to enable HTTPS locally?

1. In docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#enabling-tls said to use "symfony server:ca:install" command, but I get a error message:

*There are no commands defined in the "server:ca" namespace.* 
*Did you mean one of these?*

*doctrine:cache*

*server*

2. Then I found https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/force_https.html and tried to add

   ```
   - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
   ```

and clear cache after all. But now it redirected from http://127.0.0.1:8000 to https://127.0.0.1/ with no access to the site

So what is the correct way to configure https?

**The main reason to enable https is I want to configure sign in with Facebook, but Facebook demands https connection. So I cannot test it. Or, if you know the way to test sign in with Facebook without https - it would be the best decision!)**

Thank you in advance and have a good day who read it!)

Comment: You actually have to install a [binary called symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#installation).  Have not tried it myself.  This binary used to be the more or less standard way of creating a symfony app.  It is no longer used for that in S4 but I guess it still handles the certificate stuff.  Might be easier to just install nginx or apache locally.

Comment: @Cerad thank you! You were right) "It is no longer used for that in S4" - that's why I thought I do not need to install anything but composer.

Comment: Another reason to use a secure connection to the local server is so you can have multiple connections to the server in addition to localhost.  This is important for testing.  With unsecure connections certain features of the browser such as audio devices will not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably do not run `symfony` command correctly, or maybe you have some weird symbolic links. Here is a sample output for my system:

```
$ symfony server:ca:install

 [OK] The local Certificate Authority is installed and trusted
```

And what you quote as output looks more like `bin/console` response.

FYI, `symfony` console command can be downloaded here: http://symfony.com/download

And re your 2nd point, that configuration is valid but it does not *enable* HTTPS, it only ensures that certain URLs have protocol requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I mistakenly thought that bin/console and symfony commands might do same things (as both have "server" command).

Comment: But when I successfully installed a certificate and started the server - I saw "No input file specified.". Google gives me results only about nginx configs and etc. that I do not have. Unfortunately, I cannot find the solution for symfony server( But, anyway, thank you for the solution to my problem above!

Comment: You're welcome. If you get stuck with the other problem, you can probably post it here as another question. Or maybe as an issue in Symfony client app tracker: https://github.com/symfony/cli

Comment: BTW, that `server:ca:install` thingie works only with the server which is started by `symfony serve` command. It does not work with Encore part, or `bin/console server:run` (not directly with the latter, anyway).